# YAML pipeline: Deployment vs Jobs, ScriptPath and csmFile not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had [Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) working correctly in a YAML pipeline but when I changed it to [Deployment Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops), The path fails to work.

```
jobs:
  - job: InfrastructureAsCodeDeployment
    pool:
        name: Azure Pipelines
        vmImage: windows-2019
    steps:
    - task: "AzurePowerShell@2"
      displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: Remove Keyvault'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Connection name'
        ScriptType: 'FilePath'
        ScriptPath: 'Powershell Scripts/IAC/kv-RemoveExistingSoftDeleted.ps1'
        ScriptArguments: '-vaultName $(keyVaultName) -location "$(location)"'
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
      continueOnError: true
```

after making it to deployment Jobs :-

```
  jobs:
  - deployment: InfrastructureAsCodeDeployment
    pool:
        name: Azure Pipelines
        vmImage: windows-2019
    environment: 'DEV'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - task: "AzurePowerShell@2"
                displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: Remove Keyvault'
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: 'Connection name'
                  ScriptType: 'FilePath'
                  ScriptPath: 'Powershell Scripts/IAC/kv-RemoveExistingSoftDeleted.ps1'
                  ScriptArguments: '-vaultName $(keyVaultName) -location "$(location)"'
                  azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
                continueOnError: true
```

Tried adding 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory' to Deployment but still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra step in the beginning is needed

```
steps:
- checkout: self
```

It looks like this

```yaml
  jobs:
  - deployment: InfrastructureAsCodeDeployment
    pool:
        name: Azure Pipelines
        vmImage: windows-2019
    environment: 'DEV'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps: 
              - checkout: self 
              - task: "AzurePowerShell@2"
                displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: Remove Keyvault'
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: 'Connection name'
                  ScriptType: 'FilePath'
                  ScriptPath: 'Powershell Scripts/IAC/kv-RemoveExistingSoftDeleted.ps1'
                  ScriptArguments: '-vaultName $(keyVaultName) -location "$(location)"'
                  azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
                continueOnError: true
```

Unfortunately the documentation does not say this. 
But I found this when compared with the jobs pipeline(deployment pipeline did not have the visual step.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.